# Freemarker Expression in Expression

Tags: java, freemarker

in my template I would like to implement some dynamic logic based on the XML I am processing I want to get the currency rate from my dict in my template.

--my XML

```xml
<Message>
...
<Currency1>EUR<Currency1>
<Currency2>USD<Currency2>
...
<Message>
```

-- my template

```xml
<#assign EUR = {"AED":503178,"USD":0.923}>
{${doc.Message...Currency1}.${doc.Message...Currency2}} <-- but something like this is not possible-->
-->
```

What I am expecting is that it goes into the dict and gives me 0.923 based on the Currency in my XML.
Is there any other way which works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `namespace` [special variable](https://freemarker.sourceforge.io/docs/ref_specvar.html) as follow:

```
<#assign Currency1="EUR">
<#assign Currency2="USD">
<#assign EUR = {"AED":503178,"USD":0.923}>
${.namespace[Currency1][Currency2]}
```

But I recommend changing your model for better clarity. For example:

```
<#assign Currency1="EUR">
<#assign Currency2="USD">
<#assign rates= {
        "EUR" : {"AED":4.3,"USD":0.923},
        "USD" : {"AED":3.67,"USD":1.17}
}>
${rates[Currency1][Currency2]}
```